# How call the same post on jQuery, there is a shortcut for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to starts the same ajax request when it finishes. The reason why I'm doing that, is because the setInterval does not supply me, there is no guarantees that the all requests made in the first second will be completed until the second setInterval call.

I see everything, since a setInterval pause function (who doesn't exists) until the jQuery ajaxStop function that can be useful in this case, but for me is hard to implement, so I realized that the most logical and natural way would be call the same request inside it self when the request finishes.

Anyone has a ideia to how to call the same ajax request without write then all again inside the call back. I think that has a better way to do this, but I did not find anything about this.

Here is my code:

```
$.post('{% url "orderbook>get-available-balance" %}', {symbol: vm.base_currency}, function(response) {
                        vm.base_currency_balance = response.available_balance;
                    });
```

What I want is something like:

```
var post_1 = $.post('{% url "orderbook>get-available-balance" %}', {symbol: vm.base_currency}, function(response) {
                        vm.base_currency_balance = response.available_balance;

                        post_1();
                    });
```

There is a way to natively do this or implement this behavior in a correct way?

Sorry I'm not the Javascript guy kind.

Comment: I try, but how I loop until the previous looped request get finished?

Comment: looping isn't the solution unless you make the requests `async:false` which isn't recommended. calling an ajax call from one of its events defeats the purpose of an ajax call. what exactly are you hoping to achieve? can you elaborate?

Comment: And i don't have just one request, I've many, a while loop with a completed status may be useful, but very ugly in my opinion, mostly because I've more than 5 requests, and this five requests would be with a strange while loop code for me.

Comment: @Ted what I want is simple, I need to reproduce the same ajax call in a shortcut way, I can do this with a function and calling that function inside it self, but for me is very ugly, and maybe you guys with experience may have a better way.

Comment: sadly, there is not better way. ajax calls are ugly by nature if there're more than a couple on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the same ajax call repeatedly, then you simply need a bit of recursion, I think:

```
function post_1() {
  $.post('{% url "orderbook>get-available-balance" %}', {symbol: vm.base_currency}, function(response) {
    vm.base_currency_balance = response.available_balance;
    post_1(); //call the same function again
  });
}

//to kick things off the first time:
post_1();
```

If you want a short delay between each call (and this may get round the recursion limit as well, I think), you can do this instead:

```
//...
vm.base_currency_balance = response.available_balance;
setTimeout(post_1, 3000); //call the same function again
//...etc
```

It would be a good idea not to make the ajax call too frequent or to do long or complicated requests like this - it can badly affect the performance of your server if you get this wrong, especially if you have a lot of concurrent users.

You should also explore whether something like WebSockets would provide a more effective solution to your requirements.

Comment: and what will stop this wagon from falling of a cliff ? :)

Comment: @Ted :-) OP seems to want it to run continuously forever...it may hit the recursion limit of course...I don't know if they have some criteria for when it should stop, it's not mentioned. But this is the basic idea.

Comment: He already said that he doesn't want to use a loop and that he has 5 different calls to make. I'm puzzled though as to why you would recommend to someone else to endlessly loop ajax calls on their page. For the fun of it, maybe? :)

Comment: @Ted in my case I need it to run forever, that is the main proposal of the question, but to run a request forever is hard to implement in a performance way.r

Comment: @Ted the first line of the question clearly says "I need to starts the same ajax request when it finishes.". There's some fuzzy stuff in the comments now about 5 different calls, although it's not clear what exactly the process is and how they relate to each other, but that wasn't added until after I started writing, and it isn't part of the actual question asked.

Comment: @ADyson - I meant no offence to you, I just think that the OP is weird and that there's no right answer to his question

Comment: @Ted There are web apps which poll the server repeatedly during the lifetime of the page to check for updates without doing a full refresh. It's not an un-common requirement. If you don't do it too frequently and don't exchange too much data it can be ok and not kill the server, but more modern alternatives such as websockets are slowly starting to be the preferred method of delivering that kind of functionality.

Comment: @ADyson - I know what you mean, I have been using SignalR since 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Since your looking for a more *elegant* approach, I would do something like this:

```
var firstPostInterval = null;

function setFirstPostInterval() {
  console.log('setting timeout for setFirstPostInterval()');
  firstPostInterval = setTimeout(firstPost(), 3000);
}

function firstPost() {
  // clear timeout just in case the call is late so it won't get called again
  if (firstPostInterval != null) {
    console.log('clearing timeout for setFirstPostInterval()');
    clearTimeout(firstPostInterval);
  }

  $.post('{% url "orderbook>get-available-balance" %}', {symbol: vm.base_currency}, 
  function(response) {
    vm.base_currency_balance = response.available_balance;

    // reset timeout after finish
    setFirstPostInterval();
  });
}

// go!
firstPost();
```